# Need to run location.reload method only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I run below method without any action **only once**.I mean need to call below method on my page load due to one of my plugin is not bind properly without F5.So How can I achieve that ?

```
location.reload();
```

Comment: I believe restricting Browser functionality isn't necessarily possible - You could check the Keycode, but what about the refresh button?

Comment: Can I have more details about that ?

Comment: That's the kind of question that hides other design issues. What's really not working here? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @MackieeE Actually I need to fire above method, when my page gets load.In other words need to load 2 times.

Comment: Well, even if you did call `location.reload()` once, you've already left the current script essentially. Do you want to defer the JS until the window has fully loaded?

Comment: @plalx I tried whole day to solve the issue.But no luck.So now i need to get rid of this.If you would like you can check this link for my issue:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361151/onselect-not-bind-first-time-load?noredirect=1#comment28687521_19361151

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to do that, you can set a flag in any persistent medium you want (like localStorage, cookies, etc):

```
if (sessionStorage.getItem('pluginBugFixedByReloading') !== 'fixed' {
  sessionStorage.setItem('pluginBugFixedByReloading', 'fixed');
  location.reload();
}
```

Here is a link about some kinds of storage:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage

Before you do this, you should ask yourself: why isn't the plugin working without a refresh? Should i wait for the end of some asynchronous operation before i do something?

I don't know the details of your situation, but reloading the page seems like a very ugly hack that will probably backfire in unexpected circumstances.

Comment: The page i linked has that information: `sessionStorage Chrome 5 Firefox 2 IE 8 Opera 10.50 Safari 4`

Comment: Thanks my friend.Your idea helped me a lot.I have used html5 localStorage for this.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed there are many ways to get what you need. There is cookies for example. However, in this answer I will explain more simple way. It is using an `iframe`.

The solution depends on that your main page will be an iframe from reloading page. Suppose we have to pages: main.html and loader.html.

> Don't get confused, loader.html is going to be the page that we access
>   from the browser

```
<!-- loader.html -->
<html>
  <head>
     <title>loader</title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <iframe src="main.html" name="toLoad"></iframe>
     <script>
       toLoad.location.reload()     
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Some CSS will styling your loader.html and its iframe to make it covering well.